# Using percent sign in os.system or os.popen error

Tags: python

I'm trying to open a file with an exe by using a user defined string with the %, this never works for me. I tried os.system and os.popen. I keep getting this
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for %: 'file' and 'str'

What can I do to make it work?

```py
def showhelp():
 defaulteditor = "notepad.exe"
 print "[*] Which text viewer do you want to use? [default: notepad]"
 which = raw_input("\n\n\ntype n for notepad, or specify program.exe  >     ")
 if which != "n":
    os.popen('notepad ./help.txt')
else:
    os.popen('%r')%(which)
```

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
os.popen('%r' % which)
```

instead.

The `%` formatting operator needs the format string on the left side, and the arguments on the right. Also, if it's only one arguments you don't need the parentheses.

Answer (score 1):

maybe this can help answer your question:

```
>>> def printy(string):
    print string


>>> printy("hello %s" % "world")
hello world
>>> printy("hello %s") % "world"
hello %s

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#278>", line 1, in <module>
    printy("hello %s") % "world"
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for %: 'NoneType' and 'str'
>>>
```

as you can see, you are not including the % operator or its supplements in the right place.

you can even consult these docs: http://docs.python.org/release/2.4.4/lib/typesseq-strings.html

also included in your python help docs that came with python.

Answer (score 1):

If you use the [`subprocess` module](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html) instead of the deprecated ways to make your calls, you avoid this problem and have a cleaner program.